# QEMU-KVM: Is Guest Physical Address(GBA) same as QEMU-KVM's Virtual Address on the host?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-machine, qemu, virtual-memory, kvm

For example, if a process on the guest has data allocated on 0x8000(as in Guest Virtual Memory), and that has been mapped into 0x4000 in Guest Physical Memory Address Space, is the data located on 0x4000 in the virtual memory address space of host-side QEMU-KVM's (sub)process(per VM)? In other words, if I write new code within QEMU's source(so I can use the QEMU-KVM's page table), compile, and run it, then can I access to the data of guest process directly just with the guest's physical memory address matching to the guest virtual memory address?

Answer (score 2):

No, the page table mapping used for the user-space QEMU process is unrelated to either the page tables used by the guest itself for guest virtual -> guest physical address mapping, or to the page tables used by the KVM kernel code for guest physical address -> host physical address mapping for RAM.

When you're writing code in QEMU that needs to access guest memory, you should do so using the APIs that QEMU provides for that, which deal with converting the guest address to a host virtual address for RAM and also with handling the case when that guest address has an emulated device rather than RAM. The QEMU developer internals docs have [a section on APIs for loads and stores](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/devel/loads-stores.html), and the functions are also documented in doc comments in the header files.

Usually the best advice is "find some existing code in QEMU which is doing something basically the same as what you're trying to do, and follow that as an example".

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is about x86 platform.
QEMU+KVM use extended page table (EPT) to map host virtual addresses (HVA) to guest physical addresses (GPA). To find HVA corresponding to GPA, you should traverse EPT of your guest.

When you need to read a virtual address from your guest, you can use GDB functions in QEMU source. This snippet will read 4 bytes at `virtualAddress` in the current executing process in your guest:

```
  uint8_t instr[4];
  if( cpu_memory_rw_debug( cpu, virtualAddress, (uint8_t *)instr, sizeof( instr ), 0 ) )
  {
    printf( "Failed to read instr!\n" );
    return;
  }
```

`cpu` is an `CPUState*` of a cpu of your guest.

When you want to read an address of a concrete process in your guest, you should set `env->cr[3]` to `CR3` value of this process (`env` is an `CPUX86State*`). Dont forget to restore the original value after you finish reading. And of course read memory only when your guest is not executing, otherwise there can be races.